# Get a specific file from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've this folder and I want to get a specific file from it, how can I do that given that there could be more than one file in there.

I've tried to use `StartsWith` but wasn't able to do so, is there any way this could be done?

The file is in the `CustomerWorkSheet` folder and its name starts with the `customer id` field value. What should I use if I have this path: `.../uploads/attachments/CustomerWorkSheet/**File Name Here**`

```
IWordDocument doc = new WordDocument();
doc.Open(
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath
             ("~/Content/uploads/attachments/CustomerWorkSheet/"), 
      FormatType.Doc);
```

I need some thing like that

```
if(file.StartsWith(customerId))
```

but couldn't get the file

Comment: do you know the extension?

Comment: i use   var pattern = uniqueName + ".*"; for that so yes but it does not matter

Comment: you want to find a file using a pattern?

Comment: that is when I was saving it, what I want now is to get file that starts with CustomerId thats all

Comment: I told you because extension doesn't matter 
 var matches = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/attachments/CustomerWorkSheet") I get this but file name is the problem, how to get file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var directoryPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/attachments/CustomerWorkSheet");
var file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath).SingleOrDefault(f => f.Contains("CustomerWorkSheet/" + myCustomerId));
if(file != null){
  IWordDocument doc = new WordDocument();
  doc.open(file, FormatType.Doc);
}
```

Based on your comments, you are looking for this:

```
var filename = myDirectoryFiles.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Contains("CustomerWorkSheet/" + myCustomerId + "."));
```

Comment: this one appeared to be NULL
                        var file = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directoryPath).SingleOrDefault(f => f.Contains("CustomerWorkSheet/" + customerId));

Comment: customerId is their but SingleOrDefault(f => f.Contains("CustomerWorkSheet/" doesn't seems to work
as I explained earlier the name starts with customerID so I need the way to pick the file which starts with CustomerId rest is already done

Comment: I need some thing like that 
if(file.StartsWith(customerId))
but couldn't get the file

Comment: well, debug and look at what EnumerateFiles returns to see the pattern you need to match..
You can use contains as long as you put the folder in front and a dot after the customerId..

Comment: It's possible that the path separator is not `/`. Better use `Path.GetFileName`.

Comment: Yeah my solution can be cleaner. Any luck, @DareDevs?

Comment: Thanks @ThomasStock for the help I'd done that this way 

string[] FileArray = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/attachments/CustomerWorkSheet/"));


                    if (FileArray != null)

                    {

                        IWordDocument doc = new WordDocument();

                        doc.Open(FileArray.First(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith(CustomerId.ToString())), FormatType.Doc);


                        //doc.Open();
                    }